# Any Enthusiast code development sites to ask for someone to develop a small app?

Tags: twitter, codesite

I know this site is a great source for code help and snippets but I was wondering if anyone knows of any good site or forums where someone can help develop a small app.

The idea behind this is I need to make an app that does some custom stuff with twitter but lack the development time myself to do it, any suggestions?

Comment: Sure - I'll do it for you. I just need to do some custom stuff to your bank account first

Comment: It's not all about money Oxbow - you could learn some great new skills working on this kind of project.

Comment: That's true - I could learn the Eclipse key bindings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

http://www.rentacoder.com/RentACoder/DotNet/default.aspx
http://www.elance.com/
http://www.guru.com/emp/index.aspx
http://www.odesk.com/w/